# Copy paste values in VBA gots wrong pasting values

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code with the error. Please help me.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsT As Worksheet 

    With Workbooks("testing.xlsm") 
        Set wsT = .Sheets("Sheet4") 
        wsT.Cells(wsT.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value =.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:C1").Value 
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "test" 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see any *copy - paste*. What kind of *wrong pasting values* Please provide examples of what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: Your code should work. It copies the range "A1:C2" values of "Sheet3" into the last empty row of "Sheet4". What are your expectations from the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code and for me worked very well (I changed only `With ActiveWorkbook` for simplicity).

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsT As Worksheet

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsT = .Sheets("Sheet4")
        wsT.Cells(wsT.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value = .Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:C1").Value
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "test"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you get an error check the exact name of the sheet (if exists a "Sheet4", a "Sheet3" and a workbook named "testing.xlsm").